# How to ping an IP Address in golang

Tags: go

How can you ping an IP address from a golang application? The ultimate goal is to check if a server is online.

Does go have a way in the standard library to implement a network ping?

Comment: check this https://gist.github.com/kenshinx/5796276

Comment: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/icmp

Comment: @Jonathon-reinhart Thanks! I'll look into ICMP I wish I could mark comments as answers.

Comment: @Bacon Thanks for the gist, it looks interesting.

Comment: Why do you want to check if it is online? Depending on the reason the best way could simply be to try to open a connection

Comment: To add to user3591723's point, trying to ping a server that may or may not respond to a ping when you want to connect anyway only slows down the process. The best "ping" in this case is a SYN packet, i.e., *connect* to the server.

Comment: To monitor if some of our servers are online or not.

Comment: You can call ping on the native os.  Cross platform pings in golang aren't too bad.  For example: https://github.com/jcuga/goping

Comment: I know this is late to this, but @JimB and user3591723 doing a ping is more of finding the pinchpoint.  I have an app where I am trying to connect to someone else's API.  The other company keeps telling me "well the server is up so its all good".  Reality, I can "ping" the server, but I can't send GET or POST requests to it, or utilize the services on the server.  The company only sees that the server is up, not that the endpoints are functioning.  Having a PING would tell me and show the company "yes, the server is up, but the services are down as it can get a ping but no packets".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @desaipath mentions, there is no way to do this in the standard library. However, you do not need to write the code for yourself - it has already been done:

> https://github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping

*Note, sending ICMP packets requires root privileges*

Comment: I've actually found this later on after asking this question, but thank you for adding it!

Comment: Both go-fastping and go-ping are abandoned (https://github.com/go-ping/ping/issues/221) . Maintainers of go-ping suggest https://github.com/prometheus-community/pro-bing

Answer (score 15):

I needed the same thing as you and I've made a workaround (with `exec.Command`) for my Raspberry Pi to check if servers are online. Here is the experimental code

```
out, _ := exec.Command("ping", "192.168.0.111", "-c 5", "-i 3", "-w 10").Output()
if strings.Contains(string(out), "Destination Host Unreachable") {
    fmt.Println("TANGO DOWN")
} else {
    fmt.Println("IT'S ALIVEEE")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Although not a real ICMP ping, this is what use to probe my servers using the TCP protocol:

```
    host := "example.com"
    port := "80"
    timeout := time.Duration(1 * time.Second)
    _, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", host+":"+port, timeout)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s %s %s\n", host, "not responding", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s %s %s\n", host, "responding on port:", port)
    }
```

Comment: you should close the connection afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

@jpillora's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35194144/3966682) suggests using [`go-fastping`](http://github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping), but that library hasn't been updated since Jan 8, 2016. It may not be an issue as the logic of pinging is quite simple, but if you want a more recent package then there's [`go-ping`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sparrc/go-ping).

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

Go does not have any built-in way to ping a server in standard library.
You need to write code by yourself.

For that, you can look into [icmp section of golang library](http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/icmp). And use [this list of control messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages), to construct icmp message properly.

But, keep in mind that some server administrator shuts down ping service on their server, for *security reason*. So, If your goal is to ultimately check if server is online or not, this is not 100% reliable method.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: @JustDevInc Is servers are under your (or company's) control? If yes, then ICMP echo is not the best way to go, as described in [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/security-risk-of-ping) answer. Better way is to have a http endpoint on server, that responds to your request.

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os/exec"
)

func main() {
  Command := fmt.Sprintf("ping -c 1 10.2.201.174 > /dev/null && echo true || echo false")
  output, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", Command).Output()
  fmt.Print(string(output))
  fmt.Print(err)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, due to lack of maintainers and access, the library [go-ping](https://github.com/go-ping/ping) is no longer maintained after Jan 22, 2023. There is a new actively maintained fork: [pro-bing](https://github.com/prometheus-community/pro-bing)

```golang
pinger, err := probing.NewPinger("www.google.com")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
pinger.Count = 3
err = pinger.Run() // Blocks until finished.
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
stats := pinger.Statistics() // get send/receive/duplicate/rtt stats
```